# Scrollable form (50+ rows) inside a modal dialog much slower than same form rendered on it's own page

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, react-virtualized

I'm running into a performance issue and wondering if there's a work-around.

I have a React.js app that lets users edit rows in a database table:

[image]

Sometimes this table has many (50+) rows, so I've started using a react-virtualized List.

Either with or without react-virtualized, rendering performance (either initially or while scrolling) is ok when I put the form on it's own page:

[image]
(scrolling perf with form on it's own page)

but it becomes unusably slow if I put the same form in a modal dialog such as 
https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal#modal-example-modal

[image]

[image]
(scrolling with form inside modal)

I've checked whether components behind the modal are rendering unexpectedly, and confirmed that they're not. 
My backup solution is to put the form on a separate page, but I'd like to use this to better understand react and react-virtualized performance, so would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first screenshot, the fast one, is using React in production mode. The second, slow one shows React in development mode. (You can see `react-dom.production.mind.js` and `react-dom.development.js` in the screenshots.) This could easily account for the performance difference you're seeing.

Learn more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#use-the-production-build

Comment: Thanks, that was a dumb mistake.
I also ended up removing all transitions and animations from the semantic-ui css.